# Filter variable product orders Woocommerce

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

I am not familiar with SQL or wp_query and am in need of some help. If I have a variable product, how do I filter existing orders by either one or a set of product IDs? For instance, what should I do if I wanted to filter orders which contained the following products: blue shirt (#12), black shirt (#15), or red shirt (#16)?

I stumbled upon this code:

```
function retrieve_orders_ids_from_a_product_id( $product_id )
{
global $wpdb;

$table_posts = $wpdb->prefix . "posts";
$table_items = $wpdb->prefix . "woocommerce_order_items";
$table_itemmeta = $wpdb->prefix . "woocommerce_order_itemmeta";

// Define HERE the orders status to include in  <==  <==  <==  <==  <==  <==  <==
$orders_statuses = "'wc-completed', 'wc-processing', 'wc-on-hold'";

# Requesting All defined statuses Orders IDs for a defined product ID
$orders_ids = $wpdb->get_col( "
    SELECT DISTINCT $table_items.order_id
    FROM $table_itemmeta, $table_items, $table_posts
    WHERE  $table_items.order_item_id = $table_itemmeta.order_item_id
    AND $table_items.order_id = $table_posts.ID
    AND $table_posts.post_status IN ( $orders_statuses )
    AND $table_itemmeta.meta_key LIKE '_product_id'
    AND $table_itemmeta.meta_value LIKE '$product_id'
    ORDER BY $table_items.order_item_id DESC"
);
// return an array of Orders IDs for the given product ID
return $orders_ids;
}
```

which seemed to have the gist of what I need but I am not sure where to place this code, if I want to sort through orders and have this visible to myself (as admin) but no other, or how to modify this so as to retrieve orders for the array of product IDs.  Placing the code into functions.php in my child theme results in an error msg.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get_posts()` instead to get all orders and loop through order items to find if item product id matches `$product_id` variable. Inside the loop add the result to an array if there is a match.

```
function retrieve_orders_ids_from_a_product_id( $product_id ){

    $orders = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_type'   => wc_get_order_types(),
        'post_status' => array_keys( wc_get_order_statuses() ),
    ) );
    $orders_ids = array();

    foreach($orders as $o){
        $order_id = $o->ID;
        $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
        foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_key => $item_values ){
            $p_id = $item_values->get_product_id();
            if($p_id == $product_id){
                array_push($orders_ids, $order_id);
            }
        }
    }
    return $orders_ids;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update** - The SQL query to get the orders IDs for an array of product IDs will be:

```
function get_orders_ids_from_product_ids( $product_ids )
{
    global $wpdb;

    $product_ids = implode( ',', $product_ids ); // Converting to string

    // HERE the orders status to include
    $orders_statuses = "'wc-completed', 'wc-processing', 'wc-on-hold'";

    # Requesting All defined statuses Orders IDs for a defined product ID
    $orders_ids = $wpdb->get_col( "
        SELECT DISTINCT woi.order_id
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items as woi
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}posts AS p ON woi.order_id = p.ID
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS woim ON woi.order_item_id = woim.order_item_id
        WHERE p.post_status IN ( $orders_statuses )
        AND woim.meta_key LIKE '_product_id'
        AND woim.meta_value IN ($product_ids)
        ORDER BY woi.order_item_id DESC
    ");

    // Return an array of Orders IDs for the given Product IDs
    return $orders_ids;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

---

**USAGE:**

You can pass the resulting Orders IDs array in a variable this way *(in any other code)*:

```
    // HERE  your product IDs in the array
    $product_ids = array( 12, 15, 16 );

    // Passing the resulting array to a variable
    $Orders_ids = get_orders_ids_from_product_ids( $product_ids );
```

You will get for the desired variations of your variable products an array of Orders IDs… This works for all kind of products, including variations of a variable product.

Comment: Would this go under functions.php?

Comment: @vconfused101 Yes it goes in function.php file … I have maid **an update on the code** and added an **USAGE** at the end.

Comment: @vconfused101 Is it working for you now? It should do exactly what you are looking for…